# concatenating tuples of array within a tuple

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tuples

I have a tuple which contains many tuples. Each tuple within my main tuple has two elements --
the first element is an array with a shape of (700,) and the second
element is a integer.

Here is a small representation of my tuple:

```
x =( (np.array[3,3,3],1), (np.array[4,4,4],2), (np.array[5,5,5],3))
```

I'm looking to combine all the arrays into one big matrix, and all the integers into one column vector, which all fit into one tuple.

So my output should be something like this:

```
y= (np.array([[3,3,3],[4,4,4], [5,5,5]]),   np.array([1,2,3]))
```

One tuple with the first element as an array with shape (3,3), and the second element as an array 
     with a shape of (3,)

I'm assuming we can use one of numpy's stack methods but I can't wrap my head
around how to access all elements of the tuples to do so.

Thank you.

Comment: So, the output would be a regular 3x4 shaped array, right?

Comment: No the output would be a tuple with two arrays -- 3x3 and a 3. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Could you write down the actual expected output, because what you have shown isn't a valid one.

Comment: I will look it over. I thought I wrote everything correctly. I'm dealing with a very large data set so I tried to create a sample.

Comment: @Divakar I got confused when I read it too; ignore the `[` and `]`s and just pretend they wrote it with the spacing as two separate arrays.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm working on it right now.

Comment: @Divakar I think I fixed it now.

Comment: It looks like I could make a structured array.  One field with 3 terms, another with 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> x = ((np.array([3,3,3]),1), (np.array([4,4,4]),2), (np.array([5,5,5]),3))
>>> y = (np.array([e for e, _ in x]), np.array([i for _, i in x]))
(array([[3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5]]), array([1, 2, 3]))
```

Or, without comprehensions:

```
>>> map(np.array, zip(*x))
[array([[3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5]]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```

Comment: Map works brilliantly here, +1. I'll delete my answer since the OP changed his example from lists to arrays.

Comment: A list comprehension version of the `map`: `[np.array(i) for i in zip(*x)]`.  The key is that `zip(*x)` is effectively a list `transpose`.

Answer (score 1):

A structured array approach:

First the tuple, with corrected syntax:

```
In [392]: x =( (np.array([3,3,3]),1), (np.array([4,4,4]),2), (np.array([5,5,5]),3))
```

Input to structured array is a list of tuples, each tuple containing data for a `record`:

```
In [393]: arr=np.array(list(x), np.dtype('3i,i'))
In [394]: arr
Out[394]: 
array([([3, 3, 3], 1), ([4, 4, 4], 2), ([5, 5, 5], 3)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (3,)), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Accessing the array by field name:

```
In [395]: arr['f0']
Out[395]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5]], dtype=int32)
In [396]: arr['f1']
Out[396]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

or as a tuple of fields:

```
In [397]: (arr['f0'], arr['f1'])
Out[397]: 
(array([[3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5]], dtype=int32), array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
```